# VBScript RegExp with Characters + or -

Tags: regex, vbscript

I cannot seem to figure this out. I need the below to spit out "Market Value"

```
Function removeScenarioTags (strtoclean)
    Dim objRegExp, outputStr
    Set objRegExp = New Regexp

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global     = True
    objRegExp.Pattern    = " ?\([0-9a-zA-Z ]+\) ?"          

    Set objMatch  = objRegExp.Execute( strtoclean )
    corrected_row = strtoclean
    For Each myMatch in objMatch
        matched_value  = myMatch.Value                   
        corrected_row  = replace(corrected_row, matched_value, "")  
    Next
    removeScenarioTags = corrected_row
End Function

'----------------MAIN------------------------------------------

after_clean = removeScenarioTags("Market Value (steep+50)")
msgbox after_clean
```

Comment: You need to add the `+` to the character class: `objRegExp.Pattern = " ?\([0-9a-zA-Z +]+\) ?"`

Comment: That was quick and easy. Thanks Jan.

Comment: Have added it as an answer as well.

Comment: @mickeym1970 You do not have to worry about how to add the next char that appears in your input to the regex if you use a negated character class `[^()]+`, 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317699/3832970). Besides, your code is too  verbose and can be shrunk considerably.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the + to the character class:

```
objRegExp.Pattern = " ?\([0-9a-zA-Z+]+\) ?"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Q6LFet/1).

Answer (score 2):

You may simplify the regex based replacement by using a regex that matches parentheses with any chars inside other than parentheses, enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, and remove the match with `RegExp.Replace` method directly:

```
Function removeScenarioTags(strtoclean)
    Dim objRegExp, outputStr
    Set objRegExp = New Regexp

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "\s*\([^()]+\)\s*"

    removeScenarioTags = objRegExp.Replace(strtoclean, "")
End Function
```

See the [`\s*\([^()]+\)\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/Jdz0gZ/1) regex demo.

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(`
- `[^()]+` - 1 or more (replace with `*` to match 0 or more) chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)`
- `\s*`- 0+ whitespaces

Note that with this regex, `objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True` does not do anything meaningful and can be removed.